# Java Canvas drawString won't bold text unless running from NetBeans

Tags: java, canvas, fonts, awt

I'm making an online multiplayer game (Nothing too complex, just a top-down tank shooting game) on a Java Canvas. You would think I'm here to ask about networking stuff, sockets, etc, but I'm much farther along than that, and I've come across something strange.

Basically, there are a few strings that I'm drawing on the canvas with a bold font. When I run it from NetBeans (Not building, just pressing F6/The green run button), the text shows up bold as it should. But, when I build the project, and run the JAR file, the text is not bold.

Note:

- I tried updating Java, as I was quite a few updates behind. Didn't fix it.

Here is a code snippet to show that I am drawing the bold text correctly, but I don't know what else I would need to show for this kind of issue as the code can't be the problem.

```
g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 50));
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.drawString("Connection Failed.", x, y);
```

TL;DR - Drawing bold text on canvas isn't bold when running JAR file, but is when running from NetBeans.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a `BufferStrategy`?

Comment: I did a very quick test using both a plain and bold font and had no issues.  Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will help us better understand your issue and provide you with a better chance of getting a suitable answer to your problem

Comment: Please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a question. If you had, you would have realized that this has nothing to do with [tag:jcanvas]!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I am using a BufferStrategy.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's my bad, I didn't mean to select that one! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be creating a Font in your paint function.  Given the paint function may be called several times per second, this can be a source inefficiency, and possibly resource starvation.  Create your Font when you create your class, perhaps as a static resource, and then use the same font object in each paint call.

The Graphics object is allowed to take shortcuts when drawing objects, in the name of efficiency.  This can include not bolding large fonts, not using anti-aliasing on diagonal lines, etc.  Speed is king.  Of course, you can tell the graphics engine you care more about appearance than speed, using [Graphics2D.setRendingHint(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.Key,java.lang.Object))

```
import static java.awt.RenderingHints.*;

void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setRendingHint(KEY_RENDERING, VALUE_RENDERING_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRendingHint(KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIAS, VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

You can set multiple hints at once with [setRendingHints(Map hints)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHints(java.util.Map)).

Comment: I did everything you suggested but nothing seemed to change. I see what you were going for, but I fail to see how optimization and rendering hints change how it acts differently when running it as a test and running the actual JAR file. As far as I know, shouldn't they run the same?

Comment: When running unit tests, the JVM isn’t restarted between tests.  Settings changed in one unit test could affect another unit test.  A properly written unit test should leave the JVM in its original state, but it is possible to accidentally change JVM settings, defaults, and what not.  NetBeans May

Comment: NetBeans May start the tests in a nonstandard JVM state.  The question is which setting, option, control is needed to give the desired result.  There are other rendering hints you can try.  But please post a [mcve] and images of the correct & incorrect appearance, so we can reproduce the problem and have a hope of fixing.  Otherwise, we can only guess.